# Specific colour in equation links

Tags: hyperref, color

In hyperref package, is it possible to specify a specific color for equation links different than other link colors ?

Following are present color specifications that I am using for `hyperref` package

```
colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
urlcolor=cyan
```

(Is it possible to do it with \cref ?)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) or any other cross-referencing package?

Comment: @Werner Yes I am using `amsmath` as one of the packages.

Answer (score 19):

You can define your own link command for equations and change the (border) color for links locally.

### LaTeX with `\ref`

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{linkequation}{blue}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\refeq}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
      linkcolor=linkequation,
      linkbordercolor=linkequation,
    }%
    \ref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example}\label{sec:example}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
See section \ref{sec:example} and equation \refeq{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \refeq]

### Package `amsmath` and `\eqref`

And an example for the redefinition of `\eqref` from package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{linkequation}{blue}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\SavedEqref}{}
\let\SavedEqref\eqref
\renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
      linkcolor=linkequation,
      linkbordercolor=linkequation,
    }%
    \SavedEqref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example}\label{sec:example}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
See section \ref{sec:example} and equation \eqref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \eqref]

### Package `cleveref` and `\cref`

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{linkequation}{blue}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\creflabelformat{equation}{%
  \textup{%
    \hypersetup{
      linkcolor=linkequation,
      linkbordercolor=linkequation,
    }%
    (#2#1#3)%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example}\label{sec:example}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
See section \ref{sec:example} and \cref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \cref]

Comment: Thanks a lot. At present I am using `cleveref` package to refer to equations and all others (for example, tables, figures, sections). Is it possible to do it with `\cref` ?

Comment: please get rid of the redundant "eq." in the `\cref` example.  in fact, with the parentheses, the "equation" isn't needed either, but isn't as annoying.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, redundant "`equation`" removed.

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: But how to redefine the color of `\ref` 's linkcolor? I try to use the same method of `\eqref` but it is not work.

Comment: @user19832 See `hyperref`'s option `linkcolor`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I mean change `\ref` 's linkcolor locally, not the all of the `linkcolor`.

Comment: @user19832 `\begingroup\hypersetup{linkcolor=<color>}\ref{<label>}\endgroup` or option `linkbordercolor` for links with rectangles.

Comment: I have noticed that these new defined references do not work well in a figure caption environment. I always get an error

Comment: @Wallflower The argument of *macro* `\caption` usually moves to the `.aux` and `.lof` file. Fragile stuff can break and need protection. E.g. `\protect\hypersetup` or define a protected macro using `\DeclareRobustCommand`.