# ''Proof of Theorem x'' header trough modification of \ref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I had a problem that was solved in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243832/distinguishing-ref-and-cref-through-different-colors), and that now is coming back.

The idea was to use `\ref` for internal links with color **A**, and `\cref` with `nameinlink` option in `cleveref` (!) and color **B** for links with mathematical content.

Audrey Blumsohn kindly provided me the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor=green}

\newcommand{\mref}[3][red]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}\cref{#2}{#3}\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}}%<<<changed

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\label{sec:bla}
\begin{theorem}
\label{th:gauss}
Gauss
\end{theorem}

\section{blabla}

In section \ref{sec:bla} we found \mref{th:gauss}

And again \ref{sec:bla} we found \mref{th:gauss}

\end{document}
```

But still there is a problem. Namely, this solution does not work when I use it for cross-referencing in a proof environment, to get something like

> Proof of the theorem 1.

that in principle I should write

> \begin{proof}[Proof of \mref{thm:1}]

with 'theorem 1' written by using `\mref`.

Is there a way to get the result?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The link is missing

Comment: Even if was late, I added the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\cref` only wants a single argument, not two.

```
\newcommand{\mref}[2][red]{%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
  \cref{#2}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
}
```

This will solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor=green}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\mref}[2][red]{%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
  \cref{#2}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\label{sec:bla}
\begin{theorem}
\label{th:gauss}
Gauss
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \mref{th:gauss}]
Obvious.
\end{proof}

\section{blabla}

In section \ref{sec:bla} we found \mref{th:gauss} which is nice.

And again \ref{sec:bla} we found \mref{th:gauss} which is nice.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you something? When I use `\mref` I have a spacing problem (the word that comes next is just attached to the cross-referenced one, without spacing). Can this be fixed?

Comment: No, you don't, with the definition I gave. See edit.