# How to cross-reference an unnumbered theorem using hyperref and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref

In two previous questions  (i.e. [Distinguishing \ref and \cref through different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243832/distinguishing-ref-and-cref-through-different-colors), and [''Proof of Theorem x'' header trough modification of \ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253024/proof-of-theorem-x-header-trough-modification-of-ref)) I addressed some problems I had with `hyperref` and `cleverref`. Here there is a new problem I have, that can be exemplified by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{named}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{named}
\newtheorem*{namedtheorem}{Theorem}



\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks={true},linkcolor={red},citecolor={green}}

\newcommand{\aref}[2][blue]{%
\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
\cref{#2}%
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Bla}
\label{section:bla}


\begin{theorem}[Bla]
\label{th:bla}
Bla.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Bla Bla]
\label{thm:blabla}
Bla bla
\end{namedtheorem}


\section{Bla Bla}

In section \ref{section:bla}, we get \aref{th:bla}, but we also get \aref{thm:blabla}.


\end{document}
```

Thus, the all problem is that when I use `\aref` (the modification of `\cref`) applied to `namedtheorem`, instead of giving me the name of the theorem (e.g. "Bla Bla" in blue), it gives me "section 1" in Blue.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you for your time.

---

**Edit after comment:**

A user as kindly provided an attempt to fix the problem. Namely, to substitute `\newtheorem*` with `\newtheorem` and then use `\crefname{namedtheorem}{theorem}{theorems}` after loading `cleverref`. By doing this, the hyperlink doesn't show up anymore as `section`, but still there are two problems:

1. I don't get the name of the theorem in blue (e.g. `Bla Bla`in blue), but rather `Theorem 1`in blue;
2. If there is another theorem, no matter what is the label, when I called them, in both cases I get `theorem 1`.

Comment: maybe this helps? [cleveref and amsthm — incorrect environment name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281224/579)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: you need to replace `\newtheorem*` with `\newtheorem` and then use `\crefname{namedtheorem}{theorem}{theorems}` after  loading `cleverref`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. This actually solves only one problem, in the sense that it does not appear `section 1` in blue anymore. Still, the result is not the name of the theorem in blue. Plus, if there is another theorem in the section, they both get the same name.

Comment: You're setting up an unnumbered theorem environment called "named", and you're giving an instance of this theorem environment a `\label` (`thm:blabla`). However, since the "named" theorem style (by design!) does not increment a counter (via `\refstepcounter`), LaTeX associates the `\label` with a recently-incremented counter, which in the present case happens to be the `section` counter. Note that this problem is *not* specific to `cleveref`: You're somehow trying to generate a link, but *there's no hook to link to* via the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Comment: You may want to look into an alternative linking scheme that doesn't involve `\label` and `\[c]ref` -- the `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` macros of the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks a lot for your reply, that is truly enlightening! Concerning your advice, I would rather prefer to stick to the setting I have. Hence, I would like to know if there is some way (kinda trick) to work around the problem, considering that the reasons behind the problem are clear from your first comment.

Comment: @Kolmin - You cannot realistically stick with your current setting: it's not working, and it cannot work. In the meantime, I've posted an answer that shows (hopefully...) that it's not all that difficult to use the `\hypertarget` / `\hyperlink` mechanism to generate cross-references to unnumbered entities (e.g., unnumbered theorems) that are also hyperlinks.

Comment: @Kolmin - I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting, as the earlier title may not have been fully descriptive of what your posting is about. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: It is definitely more informative. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two types of theorems in your document -- numbered ones, of type `plain`, and unnumbered ones, of type `named`. As you've already discovered and pointed out, it's easy to assign a `\label` to a numbered theorem and to cross-reference it via `\ref`, `\cref`, or `\aref`.

Theorems of the "named" type, in contrast, do *not* have a counter associated with them. While it's possible to associate a `\label` with unnumbered theorems, doing so is not going to work (and, in fact, *cannot* work): LaTeX will merrily associate the `\label` with *some* counter that was incremented previously; in the case of your sample code, that happens to be the counter named `section`.

Note that this behavior is *not* specific to, or caused by, either the `hyperref` or the `cleveref` package.

How, then, to go about creating cross-references to unnumbered theorems? Fortunately, the `hyperref` package provides the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` mechanism for just this purpose. The former macro serves to install a "hook" (and to give a name to the hook), and the latter serves to create hyperlinks elsewhere in the document to hooks created by `\hypertarget`. Observe that whereas `\label` and `\ref`/`\cref` take *one* argument, `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` take *two* arguments. The first argument corresponds, in design, to the lone argument of `\label` and `\ref`; the second argument can be an arbitrary text string. Thus, if an object is to be cross-referenced via `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`, the first arguments of the two instructions must be the same; the second arguments, in contrast, *can but do not have to be* the same. To wit, in the following example the second argument of `\hypertarget` is `Mystery theorem` whereas the second argument of `\hyperlink` is `mystery theorem`.

Incidentally, I've set up a helper macro named `\bref` that simplifies switching the color of the cross-reference from red to some other color (default: blue). (Plus, I couldn't resist creating an opportunity to write a sentence that contains `\aref`, `\bref`, and `\cref`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{named}%
    {}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{named}
\newtheorem*{namedtheorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\aref}[2][blue]{%
    \begingroup%
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
    \cref{#2}%
    \endgroup}
\newcommand\bref[3][blue]{%
    \begingroup%
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}%
    \hyperlink{#2}{#3}%
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\section{Uno} \label{section:uno}

\begin{theorem}[Bla]\label{thm:bla}
Bla.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[\hypertarget{thm:mystery}{Mystery theorem}]
Bla bla.
\end{namedtheorem}

\section{Due}

In \cref{section:uno}, we have both \aref{thm:bla} and an unnumbered \bref{thm:mystery}{mystery theorem}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving on from your last sentence, I cannot resist from saying that it is a marvellous answer, that incidentally also solved my problem. Also, you explained the whole problem and the solution in a beautiful way, with the kind of intuition that – I find – often lacking in answers. What I mean that often you have answers that *give a fish*, but *do not really teach how to fish*. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kolmin - Many thanks for the compliment -- and many thanks for the bounty!!

Comment: Your comment above just made me remember that maybe there is a typo in your answer (at least, I used the answer with this minor modification): you write `\newcommand\bref[3][blue]`, but maybe it should be `\newcommand{\bref}[3][blue]` (notice the "maybe"... I'm not sure it doesn't work as in the answer now, but I just noticed that it looks different from what you write in the other entries and I modified accordingly).

Comment: @Kolmin - `\newcommand\bref[3][blue]{...}` and `\newcommand{\bref}[3][blue]{...}` are equivalent. For sure, Leslie Lamport (the creator of LaTeX) used the second form in his book. As both forms work equally well, which form to choose becomes mostly a matter of personal preference. As for me, I like to go for an uncluttered look in my code, and I like to economize on the use of curly braces whenever their use isn't required. Both forms are OK, though: As you develop your own programming habits, just be sure to develop a consistent style.

Comment: Sorry for this late question, but I am trying to exploit your answer for hyperlinks to steps or claims in a proof (or whatever I want). The problem is that it modifies the overall look, and instead of "Step 1.", I get "Step 1 ()." (this is if I write `[\hypertarget{step:1}{}] ` close to `\begin{step}`. Nothing changes if I drop the second couple of curly braces, but if I write something inside, then it obviously appears in the round braces in the text. *Is there a way to use your system to get the link with the simple "Step 1."?* Sorry to bother after all this time, and thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Kolmin - I'm afraid I don't fully understand your setup, and I hence don't know where the`()` after `Step 1.` is coming from. Importantantly: How is the `step` environment defined? May I ask that you post a *new question* in which you provide a minimum working example that's generating the problem behavior?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Here there is the link to my new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310486/problem-with-crossreference-by-using-hypertarget . As you will notice, the problem is essentially the one presented here. That's why I thought at the beginning it was possible to avoid a potential duplicate (or something pretty close to it) with the new question.