# Print list of theorems and their labels (using self-defined theorem environment using \newtcbtheorem)

Tags: environments, theorems, newtheorem

Suppose I have defined

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{Theorem}%
{colframe=blue!35!black,enlarge top by=0.15cm,fonttitle=\slshape,breakable}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, use counter from=mytheo]{mylemma}{Lemma}%
{colframe=blue!35!white,enlarge top by=0.15cm,fonttitle=\slshape,breakable}{lem}
```

where I can define a new theorem by

```
\begin{mytheo}{Title}{label}
blah
\end{mytheo}
```

where "Title" is what the reader will see and "label" is the thing I use for "\ref{th:label}" or "\ref{lem:label}". What I want is the ability to print out (at the end of the document, sort of like a glossary) a list of all the theorems from my document, just their "Title" and "label".

I have found [ToC like list of definitions (using theorem environments)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/toc-like-list-of-definitions-using-theorem-environments), which seems more like a Table of Contents thing than a glossary at the end thing.

Alternatively, it would also work if I could print the "label" in the document itself, next to the "Title". EDIT: this last question is answered [Passing label as argument for tcolorbox so that it is accessible by cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443483/passing-label-as-argument-for-tcolorbox-so-that-it-is-accessible-by-cleveref)

Comment: Are you aware of the showlabels package?

Comment: @Teepeemm ahh, how nice. That is good to know! In any case, I am still interested in a "theorem glossary" at the end.

Comment: @Teepeemm hmm, it doesn't seem to work for my \newtcbtheorem theorem boxes