# reference to a specific part of a subfigure in text

Tags: floats, hyperref, subfloats, autoref, pointer

Hi there I was working on a subfigure and since it's part of a pipeline I wanted to have something in my main text saying: ... (Figure 4, top right) ... (Figure 4, middle) ... (Figure 4, bottom).

Now, the subfigure part it's pretty straightforward and it appears to be correct; however, when clicking on the in-text links I'm always prompted to the whole Figure 4... What I would actually like to happens is a close-in look at the top/middle/bottom of the figure according to where I click.

Below the packages I use and how I implemented the subfigure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for inserting images
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg} %for SVG import

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=teal,
    linktoc=all
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\captionsetup[table]{font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{MSBlue}{rgb}{0.204, 0.353, 0.541}
\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % automatically adds LOF and LOT to TOC

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\bfseries\color{MSBlue}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large\bfseries\color{darkcerulean}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coolblack}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{10000}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\title{\Huge\bfseries{Pangenome-based Demographic Inference}}
\author{\LARGE{Matteo Tommaso Ungaro}}
\date{}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\color{MSBlue}}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries\color{darkcerulean}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coolblack}}

\begin{document}

...

%referring to part of the figure/specific subfigures
(\textbf{\hyperref[figure:construction]{Figure 4, top right}})
(\textbf{\hyperref[figure:mapping]{Figure 4, middle}})
(\textbf{\hyperref[figure:analyses]{Figure 4, bottom}})

%subfigure part
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includesvg[width=6.5in]{figure4_flowchart_pt1}
        \vspace{-1.1\baselineskip}
        \label{figure:construction}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includesvg[width=6.5in]{figure4_flowchart_pt2}
        \vspace{-1.1\baselineskip}
        \label{figure:mapping}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includesvg[width=6.5in]{figure4_flowchart_pt3}
        \label{figure:analyses}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption[\textbf{Workflow from pangenome construction to downstream analyses}]{\textbf{Workflow from pangenome construction to downstream analyses.} } 
\label{figure:workflow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I didn't use `\caption` for subfigures as I didn't need it, I only require a global caption for the workflow. Also, I got rid of extra white spaces between the subfigures since I want the workflow to appear as a single item. *See* image below.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: "I'm not sure what I'm dong wrong..." Since there are no `\caption` statements inside the`subfigure` environments, the `\label` statements can't latch on to anything that's specific to those `subfigure`s. Instead, all LaTeX can do is associate them with the *overall* `\caption` statement. A `subfigure` environment is nothing but a `minipage` environment that knows what to do when it encounters a `\caption` directive. Since you don't want to provide subfigure-specific captions, it's kind of pointless to even employ `subfigure` environments. Why not provide `minipage` environments directly?

Comment: @Mico Indeed, I see what you mean. I changed the `\subfigure` with `\minipage` but that doesn't seem to change the end result... is there anything else specific I need to do? Sorry but I'm quite new to LaTex, also apology I fixed the typos

Comment: Since you've chosen not to provide `subfigure`-specific captions, the basic `\label`-`\ref` mechanism cannot work since the `\label` statement have no anchor to attach themselves to. Please consult the posting [How to cross-reference an unnumbered theorem using hyperref and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286656/5001) and its accepted answer [shameless self-citation alert!] for an alternative approach to creating cross-references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've chosen not to provide `\caption` directives for the three `subfigure` environments, the associated `\label` statements *cannot* work correctly. That's what you've (re)discovered.

Fortunately, since you're employing the `hyperref` package, an alternative method for creating cross-references is available: the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` pair of directives. Its application to the problem at hand is illustrated in the example below. (Note that I chose to simplify the OP's code considerably since most of it has no bearing on the problem at hand.) `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` each take two arguments. The first argument is akin to the (single) argument of the well-known `\label` and `\ref` statements, while the second argument should be the text string you want to see typeset. Observe that the second argument can be empty.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % don't use 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont=bf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref} % for '\hypertarget' and '\hyperlink' macros
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue,linktoc=all}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
Cross-references to the \hyperlink{fig:upper}{upper}, 
\hyperlink{fig:middle}{middle}, and \hyperlink{fig:lower}{lower} 
parts of \cref{figure:workflow}.

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % no need for 'subfigure' overhead
    \color{red} % omit this instruction in the real document
    \hypertarget{fig:upper}{} % note: 2nd arg. is empty
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure4_flowchart_pt1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace*{-0.6mm}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \color{yellow} % omit this instruction in the real document
    \hypertarget{fig:middle}{} % note: 2nd arg. is empty
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure4_flowchart_pt2}
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace*{-0.6mm}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \color{blue} % omit this instruction in the real document
    \hypertarget{fig:lower}{} % note: 2nd arg. is empty
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure4_flowchart_pt3}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Workflow from pangenome construction to downstream analyses.} 
\label{figure:workflow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works like a charm!!! Thank you so much, I actually needed a bit of code to understand better. I tried to replicate from the post you linked me to but all I got were `\hyperlinks` pointing to my first page... I missed out the context and content dependent `\hypertarget` which I was misplacing in the in-text part of the figure. Thanks again!